# where should i put the button save codes into this codes that i sent here? because i'd like to save into another table

Tags: vb.net

i put this code because i used combobox and they fill my two textbox,but when try to save its not saving the data that i put

this is the code

```
Sub loaddata()
    Try
        reload("SELECT * FROM NAME", STUDENT)

       STUDENT.DataSource = dt
        STUDENT.DisplayMember = "NAME"
        STUDENT.ValueMember = "ID"
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub NAME_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NAME.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        Dim sql As String
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        strcon.Open()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT where NAME LIKE '%" & NAME.Text & "%'"
        cmd.Connection = strcon
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            GENDER.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("GENDER").ToString
            ADDRESS.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(" ADDRESS").ToString

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        strcon.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

please show me how to put the save codes here,because i use only the BindingNavigator1 to save, but it does not save, sorry if my grammar is wrong because i'm not a fluent in english

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME TO FIX THIS, I AM JUST A BEGINNER ,THANKS IN ADVANCED

Comment: Do not write empty `Catch` blocks! They will just swallow errors and you will not know what is wrong. Forgo the `Try...End Try` until the code is working or at least add a `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` to the `Catch`

Comment: Use Parameters. You are risking sql injection.

Comment: What event is going to trigger the save? Do you want to save all the data from one table to the other? Is the schema identical? Do you only want to save the data on the selected student? Will the data change in the application so the data in the other table is different from the original table?

Comment: I am guessing that STUDENT is a combo box. Why are you passing this to the reload method?

Comment: Where does the data in the NAME control come from? If it comes from the database why are you using LIKE instead of = in the Select query?

Comment: Mary thanks for your response, yes i want to save to the another table, because i have a datagridview and the other textboxes is stored binding source, but the i used combobox and i take the from the combo box in other table to make it fill on the two textbox at the same, when i finish to put the codes on the combobox, and i fill some data in other textboxes and when i save it, it can't save the data that i fill

Comment: sorry i dont have any idea on vb.net, so i just want to learn

Comment: can you give me a example codes for combo box that can fill 2 textbox and they will save?

Answer (score 0):

I know we have a language barrier but we are both trying our best. I have provided a few examples of code to interact with a database.

It is a good idea to keep you database code separate from you user interface code. If you want to show a message box in you `Try` code, keep the `Try` in the user interface code. The error will bubble up from the database code to the calling code.

`Using...End Using` blocks take care of disposing of database objects. Parameters protect against Sql injection because parameter values are not considered executable code by the database. Note that for OleDb data sources the order that the parameters appear in the sql statement must match the order that they are added to the Parameters collection.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim dt = GetOriginalData()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function GetOriginalData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your first connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select ID, Name From Table1;")
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        InsertData(CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedValue), ComboBox1.SelectedText, txtGender.Text, txtAddress.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub InsertData(id As Integer, name As String, gender As String, address As String)
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your second connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert Into Table2 (ID, Name, Gender, Address) Values (@ID, @Name, @Gender, @Address);", cn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id
            .Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = name
            .Add("@Gender", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = gender
            .Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = address
        End With
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```